# Replace gulp with Webpack for static site

Tags: angularjs, gulp, webpack, frontend

Here is my project structure

[image: Project Folder]

My goal is to generate stylus files into css, compile the jade files into HTML and image optimization. There is nothing much happening in the js folder, the js files need to be minified and in some instances, need to be combined into a single js file into dist/js folder. However I intend to use AngularJS, KendoUI and BrowserSync onto this project. I usually use Gulp to achieve the task. I would like to know if Webpack can make my life easier. Can I achieve the same using Webpack instead of Gulp. Is it worth the effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes you can use webpack!

Webpack can do much more then gulp, gulp is a only task runner on the other hand webpack is a bundler for modules. The main purpose is to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser, yet it is also capable of transforming, bundling, or packaging just about any resource or asset.
I used gulp before webpack and i have to admit it did the job but was very complicated for with all those tasks and now i let webpack to do the hard job :-)

[Learn more about webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)

[Simple configuration from my seed](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed/tree/master/config)

Comment: Cool.. I wanted to hear that. However the configuration seems little confusing for me. I'll try it out anyway. Thanks JSingh. Kindly let me know any links where I can grasp the concepts easily.

Comment: Yes it's just that part configuration which is a bit confusing but once you understand the concept everything will be easy.  You can start by simple input and output and later start using plugins and later advanced stuff like chucking and much more  you are welcome